# convert string into date format

Tags: java, android, string, date

I want this format  `6 Dec 2012 12:10`

```
  String time = "2012-12-08 13:39:57 +0000 ";

  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
  Date date = sdf.parse(time);

  System.out.println("Time: " + date);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for reply...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first **parse** your date string (Use [`DateFormat#parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method) to get the **`Date`** object using a format that matches the format of `date string`.

And then **format** that Date object (Use [`DateFormat#format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method) using the required format in `SimpleDateFormat` to get string.

```
String time = "2012-12-08 13:39:57 +0000";

Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z").parse(time);
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);

System.out.println(str);
```

**Output: -**

```
08 Dec 2012 19:09:57
```

`Z` in the first format is for [RFC 822 TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) to match `+0000` in your date string. See [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for various other options to be used in your date format.

Comment: I got this in log.... java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character - 'X'

Comment: @kettu.. Well, it's working in my case. Anyways, try using `Z` instead of `X`. `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"`

Comment: Got the ans with this... date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(time1);
    String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm").format(date);  Thank you so much..

Comment: @kettu.. Oh! You wanted just till `mm`? Yeah just noticed in the question. Anyways, good that you got it. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

change `SimpleDateFormat` to:

```
String time = "2012-12-08 13:39:57 +0000";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formatedTime = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("Time: " + formatedTime);
```

Comment: that's I know but I got unparsable string exception.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at SimpleDateFormat. The code goes something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputString));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date=simpleDateFormat.parse("23-09-2008");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat Class to do this!
such:

```
DateFormat mydate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = mydate1.parse(time);
```